# How to share your android application via Facebook,email and sms?

Tags: android, facebook, email, android-intent, sms

What is the procedure or how to code to share your android app via Facebook,sms and e-mail?

A simple question,But a question that puzzels me!!!

Is  it by that FB-android SDk...and all???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on that sharing button

```
 String shareBody = "You app link for google play";
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```